# Unable to run a script through crontab in linux

Tags: linux, crontab

When I try to run a script through `crontab`, it doesn't work. I don't see my script running when I run `ps aux.

But it works perfectly when I run it manually. Any reason why it's not working?

My script location: `/home/my location/myscript`

Crontab:

```
* * * * * /home/my location/myscript
```

Comment: What is the exact crontab entry?  The one you posted here would break because "my location" has a space in it.  Also, is the execute bit set on your script?  What user is the crontab for? Some OS's will limit who can run cron.

Comment: Can you be more exact than just "it doesn't work"? Have you tried to debug the script?

Comment: Actually "my location" refers to my working directory. Its /home/ec2-user/. The crontab entry is: * * * * * /home/ec2-user/connect. Connect is a script file. When I try to run the above script manually it runs.

Comment: Yes, I have set the execute bit for the script, for both user and group.

Comment: My OS is amazon linux 2. The cronjob is for the default user of amazon ec2 instance.

Comment: The script is just a set of two commands. First line is to cd into my working directory. 2nd line is to run my python script.

Comment: Also, the script runs when I run it through command